# How to launch a Java Web start application with dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm trying to migrate a Java applet to a Java web start application. The applet was activated from a JavaScript with several parameters, some are not hard-coded (`sessionId`, `tempFilePath`):

```
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters);
```

In order to migrate the applet I'm using a simple JNLP file with `applet-desc` tag. And from the JavaScript I call:

```
deployJava.launchWebStartApplication('$jnlp_path');
```

I just can't understand how to pass to the web start application the parameters that were created by the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out that using `deployJava.launchWebStartApplication(...)` triggers security restrictions in Chrome and IE.
What I did is kind of work around: I sent an **HTTP request** to my server and the server's response was a **JNLP** content. 
On the server side, I edited the JNLP on runtime and each time I inserted the required parameters.
When the browsers receive the JNLP content they trigger the download of the required jar.
And that's it!