# How to migrate a Java applet to Java Web Start

Tags: applet, java-web-start

At work, we have an old web-based platform that uses several Java applets.  We are finally starting to replace this platform, but it's going to take at least a year to do so.  With Java 9 coming out next month and deprecating the applet API, I'm looking for a way to keep these applets limping along until the platform is replaced.  On an Oracle page I found:

> Java Web Start technology has built-in support for applets. It is
>   possible to run your applet directly with Java Web Start technology
>   without any re-compilation of the applet. All you need do is to
>   convert your applet HTML tags to a Java Network Launching Protocol
>   (JNLP) file, using the JNLP applet-desc element.

So, I created a test JNLP file, a simple HTML file with a link to the JNLP file, and it actually worked on the first attempt.  But several of the `<param>` elements in the current `<applet>` tag are generated dynamically at runtime.  **First question:** is there a way to dynamically supply those params instead of writing them to a JNLP file?  (edit: looks like yes, with some hoop-jumping: [SO #37508597](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508597/how-to-launch-a-java-web-start-application-with-dynamic-parameters))

**Second question:** while my simple test worked, I also ended up with two open windows.  One was empty (I'm assuming this is the one I described with required `height` and `width` values in the `<applet-desc>` JNLP tag?) and another with the actual application in it (the applet displays a graph of user-selected values/options).  Is there any way to prevent having two windows open?

**Third question:** when the applet API is finally removed from Java, will the JNLP `<applet-desc>` tag still work?  Meaning, will an applet still be able to be executed via JNLP?

We are trying to avoid having to do any actual Java code changes to the applets. as we don't have any in-house Java developers any more